# Error al querer actualizar la información de un CRUD en un archivo de texto con PHP

Tags: php, base-de-datos, crud

Cordial saludo, estuve realizando un pequeño ejercicio CRUD con PHP para familiarizarme con el lenguaje, sin embargo, no e podido lograr que mi función para editar se desempeñe adecuadamente, pues tras presionar el botón de la modal para edición la pagina se recarga sin haber actualizado nada.

Intente realizar revisiones con "inspeccionar" y IA pero nada. A continuación muestro las pagina que estoy empleando para gestionar métodos y presentar la información. Agradezco su colaboración si es posible ya que realemente no entiendo porque no funciona

La primera clases.php la funcion que no sirve es "editarNoticia":

```
<?php

class Noticia
{
    //Declaracion  de las variables que se utilizaran en la cl
    private $id;
    private $titulo;
    private $fecha;
    private $autor;
    private $noticia;

    // constructor de la clase
    public function __construct($id, $titulo, $fecha, $autor, $noticia)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->titulo = $titulo;
        $this->fecha = $fecha;
        $this->autor = $autor;
        $this->noticia = $noticia;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitulo()
    {
        return $this->titulo;
    }

    public function getFecha()
    {
        return $this->fecha;
    }

    public function getAutor()
    {
        return $this->autor;
    }

    public function getNoticia()
    {
        return $this->noticia;
    }
}

class gestorNoticia
{
    private $noticias = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cargarNoticias();
    }

    public function getNoticias()
    {
        return $this->noticias;
    }

    //Metodos

    private function cargarNoticias()
    {
        $archivo = "data.txt";
        if (file_exists($archivo)) {
            $lineas = file($archivo, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
            foreach ($lineas as $linea) {
                $datos = explode("|", $linea);
                $id = $datos[0];
                $titulo = $datos[1];
                $fecha = $datos[2];
                $autor = $datos[3];
                $noticia = $datos[4];

                // Verificar si la noticia ya existe antes de agregarla
                $noticiaExistente = false;
                foreach ($this->noticias as $not) {
                    if ($not->getId() == $id) {
                        $noticiaExistente = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!$noticiaExistente) {
                    $this->noticias[] = new Noticia($id, $titulo, $fecha, $autor, $noticia);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function agregarNoticia($id, $titulo, $fecha, $autor, $noticia)
    {
        // Verificar si la noticia ya existe antes de agregarla
        $noticiaExistente = false;
        if (file_exists("data.txt")) {
            $lineas = file("data.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
            foreach ($lineas as $linea) {
                $datos = explode("|", $linea);
                if ($datos[0] == $id) {
                    $noticiaExistente = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!$noticiaExistente) {
            // Create a new string with the noticia data
            $str = $id . "|" . $titulo . "|" . $fecha . "|" . $autor . "|" . $noticia . "\n";

            // Write the new noticia string to the file
            file_put_contents("data.txt", $str, FILE_APPEND);

            // Add the new noticia to the $this->noticias array
            $this->noticias[] = new Noticia($id, $titulo, $fecha, $autor, $noticia);
        }
    }

    public function eliminarNoticia($id)
    {
        // Buscar la noticia con el ID proporcionado en el array de noticias
        foreach ($this->noticias as $indice => $noticia) {
            if ($noticia->getId() == $id) {
                // Eliminar la noticia del array
                unset($this->noticias[$indice]);
                // Reindexar el array después de eliminar la noticia
                $this->noticias = array_values($this->noticias);
                // Sobrescribir el archivo con las noticias restantes
                $archivo = "data.txt";
                file_put_contents($archivo, '');

                // Escribir las noticias restantes en el archivo usando la función agregarNoticia()
                foreach ($this->noticias as $noticia) {
                    $this->agregarNoticia($noticia->getId(), $noticia->getTitulo(), $noticia->getFecha(), $noticia->getAutor(), $noticia->getNoticia());
                }

                // Redireccionar a recibe.php
                header("Location: recibe.php");
                exit(); // Asegurar que el script se detenga después de redireccionar
            }
        }
    }

    public function editarNoticia($id, $nuevoTitulo, $nuevaFecha, $nuevoAutor, $nuevaNoticia)
    {
        foreach ($this->noticias as $noticia) {
            if ($noticia->getId() == $id) {
                // Actualizar los datos de la noticia
                $noticia->titulo = $nuevoTitulo;
                $noticia->fecha = $nuevaFecha;
                $noticia->autor = $nuevoAutor;
                $noticia->noticia = $nuevaNoticia;

                // Sobrescribir el archivo con las noticias actualizadas
                $archivo = "data.txt";
                $contenido = "";
                foreach ($this->noticias as $not) {
                    $str = $not->getId() . "|" . $not->getTitulo() . "|" . $not->getFecha() . "|" . $not->getAutor() . "|" . $not->getNoticia() . "\n";
                    $contenido .= $str;
                }
                file_put_contents($archivo, $contenido);

                // Redireccionar a recibe.php
                header("Location: recibe.php");
                exit(); // Asegurar que el script se detenga después de redireccionar
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Y la segunda pagina donde se presenta la informacion es recibe.php:

```
<?php
include "lib/header.php";
include "clases.php";

// Crear un objeto gestorNoticia
$manejador = new gestorNoticia();

// Verificar si se ha enviado el formulario para agregar una noticia
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    // Obtener los valores del formulario
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $autor = $_POST['autor'];
    $noticia = $_POST['noticia'];

    // Utilizar el método agregarNoticia
    $manejador->agregarNoticia($id, $titulo, $fecha, $autor, $noticia);
}

// Verificar si se ha enviado la solicitud para eliminar una noticia
if (isset($_GET['eliminar'])) {
    // Obtener el ID de la noticia a eliminar
    $idNoticiaEliminar = $_GET['eliminar'];

    // Llamar a la función eliminarNoticia del gestor de noticias
    $manejador->eliminarNoticia($idNoticiaEliminar);
}

// Verificar si se ha enviado el formulario para editar una noticia
if (isset($_POST['editar'])) {
    // Obtener los valores del formulario de edición
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $nuevoTitulo = $_POST['titulo'];
    $nuevaFecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $nuevoAutor = $_POST['autor'];
    $nuevaNoticia = $_POST['noticia'];
    // Utilizar el método editarNoticia
    $manejador->editarNoticia($id, $nuevoTitulo, $nuevaFecha, $nuevoAutor, $nuevaNoticia);
}

?>

<style>
    body {
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #9CCC65 0%, #8BC34A 20%, #7CB342 40%, #689F38 60%, #558B2F 80%, #33691E 100%);
        /* Gradient ajustado al estilo Frutiger Aero */
        background-size: 800px;
        /* Adjust for larger patterns */
        animation: animateBackground 10s ease-in-out infinite;
        /* Animation for movement */
    }

    @keyframes animateBackground {
        from {
            background-position: 0 0;
        }

        to {
            background-position: -800px 0;
        }
    }
</style>

<h1>Noticias actuales</h1>

<div class="container-fluid"> <!-- Aumento del ancho del contenedor -->
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12"> <!-- Aumento del ancho -->
            <table class="table table-bordered table-dark">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Título</th>
                        <th>Fecha</th>
                        <th>Autor</th>
                        <th>Noticia</th>
                        <th>Acciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    // Verificar si el array de noticias no está vacío antes de iterar sobre él
                    if (!empty($manejador->getNoticias())) {
                        $noticias = $manejador->getNoticias();
                        foreach ($noticias as $noticia) {
                    ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $noticia->getTitulo(); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $noticia->getFecha(); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $noticia->getAutor(); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $noticia->getNoticia(); ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="confirmarEliminar(<?php echo $noticia->getId(); ?>)">
                                        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> <!-- Ícono de bote de basura -->
                                    </a>

                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" data-id="<?php echo $noticia->getId(); ?>" data-titulo="<?php echo $noticia->getTitulo(); ?>" data-fecha="<?php echo $noticia->getFecha(); ?>" data-autor="<?php echo $noticia->getAutor(); ?>" data-noticia="<?php echo $noticia->getNoticia(); ?>">
                                        <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i> <!-- Ícono de lápiz -->
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    <?php
                        }
                    } else {
                        // En caso de que no haya noticias disponibles
                        echo "<tr><td colspan='5'>No hay noticias disponibles</td></tr>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
//Incluir la pagina footer
include "lib/footer.php";
?>

<!--- SCRIPT PARA CONFIRMAR ELIMINAR --->
<script>
    function confirmarEliminar(idNoticia) {
        // Mostrar un modal de confirmación
        if (confirm('¿Estás seguro de querer eliminar esta noticia?')) {
            // Si el usuario confirma, redirigir a la URL de eliminar
            window.location.href = "?eliminar=" + idNoticia;
        } else {
            // Si el usuario cancela, no hacer nada
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<!-- Modal de edición -->
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="editModalLabel">Editar Noticia</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="id" class="form-label">Id:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" readonly required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="titulo" class="form-label">Título</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titulo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="fecha" class="form-label">Fecha</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fecha">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="autor" class="form-label">Autor</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="autor">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="noticia" class="form-label">Noticia</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="noticia" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnGuardarCambios">Guardar cambios</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Script de edicion -->
<script>
    $('#editModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var id = button.data('id');
        var titulo = button.data('titulo');
        var fecha = button.data('fecha');
        var autor = button.data('autor');
        var noticia = button.data('noticia');
        // Establecer valores en los campos del formulario
        var modal = $(this);
        modal.find('#id').val(id);
        modal.find('#titulo').val(titulo);
        modal.find('#fecha').val(fecha);
        modal.find('#autor').val(autor);
        modal.find('#noticia').val(noticia);
    });

    $('#btnGuardarCambios').click(function() {
        var id = $('#id').val();
        var titulo = $('#titulo').val();
        var fecha = $('#fecha').val();
        var autor = $('#autor').val();
        var noticia = $('#noticia').val();
        
        $.post('recibe.php', {
            editar: '1',
            id: id,
            titulo: titulo,
            fecha: fecha,
            autor: autor,
            noticia: noticia
        }, function(data) {
            // Recargar la página después de editar la noticia
            location.reload();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Adjunto tambien un link a un github por si acaso: [Ejercicio 1](https://github.com/DavidNoguera1/Ejercicio-PHP1)

Nuevamente agradezco su colaboración si es posible.

Comment: a ver... yo te sugiero que si vaz a trabajar con php te enfoques en varios puntos: separar el codigo del front y el back end ... por que? facilita la escalabilidad y por ende la validacion y/o debug de problemas.

Comment: ahora me gustaria conocer mas sobre cual es el error "sin haber actualizado nada." no dice poco ... si hay un refresh hay que ver si es parte de lo que has desarrollado y/o evitarlo para pdoer ver si hay algun output de error.

Comment: verifica en el log de errores a ver si hay algun indicio mas preciso sobre errores

Answer (score 2):

Las propiedades de tu clase `Noticia` son `private`, y eso está bien, porque encapsulas dichas propiedades, impidiendo que se modifiquen arbitrariamente:

```
class Noticia
{
    //Declaracion  de las variables que se utilizaran en la cl
    private $id;
    private $titulo;
    private $fecha;
    private $autor;
    private $noticia;

    // ...
}
```

En consecuencia, desde fuera de la clase no puedes modificar esas propiedades, como intentas aquí:

```
public function editarNoticia($id, $nuevoTitulo, $nuevaFecha, $nuevoAutor, $nuevaNoticia)
    {
        foreach ($this->noticias as $noticia) {
            if ($noticia->getId() == $id) {
                
                /*
                   ERROR, no puedes modificar 
                   propiedades privadas de $noticia
                   directamente en este contexto
                   con algo como $instancia->propiedad=$valor
                   Debes modificar propiedades privadas
                   con un setter, es decir, algo como
                   $instancia->elSetter($elValor) 
                */

                $noticia->titulo = $nuevoTitulo;
                $noticia->fecha = $nuevaFecha;
                $noticia->autor = $nuevoAutor;
                $noticia->noticia = $nuevaNoticia;
                //...
     }
}
```

Para corregir el error, vamos a crear un *setter* para cada propiedad y usar ese *setter*. También podrías  declarar las propiedades como `public`, en cuyo caso sí podrías modificarlas directamente, pero esto rompe el encapsulamiento.

Así debería funcionar, salvo otros errores en tu código:

#### `Noticia`

```
class Noticia
{
    //Declaracion  de las variables que se utilizaran en la cl
    private $id;
    private $titulo;
    private $fecha;
    private $autor;
    private $noticia;

    // constructor de la clase
    public function __construct($id, $titulo, $fecha, $autor, $noticia)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->titulo = $titulo;
        $this->fecha = $fecha;
        $this->autor = $autor;
        $this->noticia = $noticia;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitulo()
    {
        return $this->titulo;
    }

    public function getFecha()
    {
        return $this->fecha;
    }

    public function getAutor()
    {
        return $this->autor;
    }

    public function getNoticia()
    {
        return $this->noticia;
    }


    /*
        Agregamos los setter
    */

    public function setTitulo($titulo)
    {
        $this->titulo=$titulo;
    }

    public function setFecha($fecha)
    {
        $this->fecha=$fecha;
    }

    public function setAutor($autor)
    {
        $this->autor=$autor;
    }

    public function setNoticia($noticia)
    {
        $this->noticia=$noticia;
    }

}
```

#### En `editarNoticia`

```
public function editarNoticia($id, $nuevoTitulo, $nuevaFecha, $nuevoAutor, $nuevaNoticia)
{
    foreach ($this->noticias as $noticia) 
    {
        if ($noticia->getId() == $id) 
        {
                
            /* Usamos los setter */

            $noticia->setTitulo($nuevoTitulo);
            $noticia->setFecha($nuevaFecha);
            $noticia->setAutor($nuevoAutor);
            $noticia->setNoticia($nuevaNoticia);
                //...
        }
    }
}
```

Para más detalles, [consulta el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.visibility.php).

Finalmente, una nota sobra la *convención de nombre*. En tu método `editarNoticia` los prefijos `$nuevo...`  o `$nueva...` son **redundantes**. El nombre del método : *editar* ya hace suponer que esos parámetros son nuevos, por tanto esos prefijos **no aportan nada a la comprensión del código**, y para lo único que sirven ahí es para tener un código más verboso o más largo.

El método quedaría mejor escrito de este modo:

```
public function editarNoticia($id, $titulo, $fecha, $autor, $noticia)
{
    foreach ($this->noticias as $noticia) 
    {
        if ($noticia->getId() == $id) 
        {
                
            /* Usamos los setter */

            $noticia->setTitulo($titulo);
            $noticia->setFecha($fecha);
            $noticia->setAutor($autor);
            $noticia->setNoticia($noticia);
                //...
        }
    }
}
```

Quitamos la palabra `$nuevo` o `$nueva` 4 x 2 veces, lo cual supone **40 caracteres menos** y no perdemos absolutamente nada en comprensión del código por lo ya dicho: si estamos dentro de un método que se prefija *editar*, ya asumimos que esos parámetros son nuevos.

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad :))))

Comment: @DavidN recuerda marcar la respuesta de cedano como correcta